# Converting @project.end_date.strftime("%b %Y") to defined locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-4, strftime

I'm outputting `Date` attributes with the following method

```
@project.end_date.strftime("%b %Y")
```

What is the simplest way to localize this date such that it displays in the locale defined in `application.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use Rails' #l helper method like so:

```
l @project.end_date
```

You can also use a format you defined in locales .yml file:

```
l @project.end_date, format: :short

# config/locales/pirate.yml
pirate:
  time:
    formats:
      short: "arrrround %H'ish"
```

The [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) covers this. Hope that helps!